# Laplace transform of the product of two gammas

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, laplace-transform

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are both gamma distributed with shapes $a,b$ and unit scales / unit rates. To fix ideas, X has Laplace transform given by:

$$L_X(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{-tX}) =  (1 + t)^{-a}$$

How can we compute the Laplace transform of the independent product $Z=XY$, that is the integral:

$$L_{XY}(t) = \mathbb{E}(e^{-tXY}) = \mathbb{E}(L_Y(tX)) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} (1+tx)^{-b} x^{a-1} e^{-x} \partial x \text{ ?}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} (1+tx)^{-b} x^{a-1} e^{-x} \,dx=$$
$$\qquad=t^{-a}  \, _1F_1\left(a;a-b+1;\frac{1}{t}\right)\frac{ \Gamma (b-a)}{\Gamma (b)}+t^{-b}  \, _1F_1\left(b;b-a+1;\frac{1}{t}\right)\frac{\Gamma (a-b)}{\Gamma (a)}.$$

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function, could-nt it be framed as $t^{-a} U(a,a-b+1,\frac{1}{t})$, where U is the Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function ?

Comment: Yes it is ! Thanks a lot for pointing these functions to me ?